# What would be an F# equivalent of the C# code using async?

Tags: f#, async-await, c#-to-f#

I am struggling to write an F# code that would sequentially await for some asynchronous method calls. I am familiar with F# async workflows but can't figure out how to map to it a simple case.

Let's take as an example an async XmlReader. Here's how the C# code might look:

```
using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input), new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{
    while (await r.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (r.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Console.WriteLine(r.LocalName);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                Console.WriteLine(await r.GetValueAsync());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If this code didn't use async calls, we could just rewrite it in F# using recursion and pattern matching. But it uses ReadAsync and GetValueAsync, how they can be expressed in F# counterpart?

Comment: why not just use recursion?  I don't see anything that would prevent it

Comment: A C# to F# conversion (done badly) here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-store-app/blob/master/Shared/Data/WebService.cs https://github.com/xamarin/shirt-store-fsharp/blob/master/Shared/WebService.fs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is completely untested, but I think gets the point across.  The essence of it is that you need to convert `Task` to `Async` using `Async.AwaitTask` then the rest of it is pretty obvious.

```
let doRecursiveAsyncThing input = async {
    use r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input), new XmlReaderSettings(Async = true ))
    let loop x = async {
        let! noteType = r.ReadAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        match noteType with
        | XmlNodeType.Element -> Console.WriteLine r.LocalName
                                 do! loop x
        | XmlNodeType.Text    -> let! value = r.GetValueAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                                 Console.WriteLine value
                                 do! loop x
        | _                   -> () }

    }
    do! loop r
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was trying to achieve. I missed Async.AwaitTask in my attempts to write similar code.

Comment: Note the helper function for async here: https://github.com/xamarin/shirt-store-fsharp/blob/master/Shared/Helpers.fs

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @BentTranberg https://github.com/xamarin/FSXamarinStore/blob/master/Shared/Helpers.fs#L42